# Using the BindAttribute Globally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In a ASP.NET MVC (4) application, I am using a 3rd party Javascript library that auto-magically sends back a query string parameter with a poor name (IMO). I can intercept this value in model binding with the following:

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Bind(Prefix="rp")] int pageSize = 50) 
{
}
```

However, this code inside all the places where I use paging gets tiresome pretty quickly.

**Is it possible inside ASP.NET MVC to globally set a [BindAttribute] with a specific prefix/replacement combination?**

A workaround would be to modify the Javascript library (undesirable); or get the parameter out of the `Request.QueryString` property manually; but I was hoping to keep things cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller action(s):

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model) 
{
    ...
}
```

and then write a custom model binder for this view model:

```
public class MyViewModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelName = "rp";
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```

that will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyViewModel), new MyViewModelBinder());
```